# How to include hyperlink within Javascript string array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to the string -- and I've attempted using both .link and .innerHTML - tho I think I may be misunderstanding what I ought to do (very new to this). Below is my code:

```
<div id="typedtext"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set up text to print, each item in array is new line
var aText = new Array(
"Hi, I'm Krishaan!", "A few words, wish I could add a link here", "Here are 
some words." ,"thanks a million for any help -- click here for more."
);
var iSpeed = 100; // time delay of print out
var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines
var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var iRow; // initialise current row

function typewriter()
{
sContents =  ' ';
iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex-iScrollAt);
var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

while ( iRow < iIndex ) {
sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
}
destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) + 
"_";
if ( iTextPos++ == iArrLength ) {
iTextPos = 0;
iIndex++;
if ( iIndex != aText.length ) {
iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
}
} else {
setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
}
}
```

Comment: You should strongly consider using indentation while writing code. It'll make refactoring and debugging much easier, both for you and for others who have to read it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance -- you're right, I will make sure to be more diligent w this in the future, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with standard HTML, you can simply wrap your desired link in `<a href='location'>text</a>` whilst outputting it through your JavaScript:

```js
// set up text to print, each item in array is new line
var aText = new Array("Hi, I'm Krishaan!", "A few words, wish I could add a link here", "Here are some words.", "thanks a million for any help--click <a href='http://www.google.com'>here</a> for more.");
var iSpeed = 100; // time delay of print out
var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines
var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var iRow; // initialise current row

function typewriter() {
  sContents = ' ';
  iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex - iScrollAt);
  var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

  while (iRow < iIndex) {
    sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
  }
  destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) +
    "_";
  if (iTextPos++ == iArrLength) {
    iTextPos = 0;
    iIndex++;
    if (iIndex != aText.length) {
      iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
      setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
    }
  } else {
    setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
  }
}

typewriter();
```

```html
<div id="typedtext"></div>
```

Note that as your array uses double quotes, your hyperlink will need to use single quotes!

Comment: amazing, I tried that before but I obviously botched it because I used " instead of ' -- thanks a ton!